# Failure Installing DotNet 4.6.1 via Chocolatey using DSC cChocoPackageInstaller

Tags: azure, dsc, chocolatey, .net-4.6.1

I'm attempting to set up a server Windows 2012 R2 in Azure via ARM templates and DSC.  The DSC script runs the cChocoPackageInstaller to install dotnet4.6.1 (after running the cChocoInstaller).  It looks like this:

```
cChocoInstaller Choco
{
    InstallDir = "c:\choco"
}

cChocoPackageInstaller DotNet461 
{            
    Name = "dotnet-461" 
    DependsOn = "[cChocoInstaller]Choco" 
}
```

The DotNet installer is downloaded but it ultimately fails when it is run.  The log looks like this (I've excerpted just the errors here).

```
2016-06-17 13:05:52,001 [DEBUG] - Running 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin' with exeToRun:'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\dotnet-461\4.6.01055.006\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe', statements: '/q /norestart /log "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\net461.log" ' 
2016-06-17 13:05:52,001 [DEBUG] - Elevating Permissions and running ["C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\dotnet-461\4.6.01055.006\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /log "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\net461.log" ]. This may take a while, depending on the statements.
2016-06-17 13:05:52,110 [DEBUG] - Setting RunAs for elevation
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - The application cannot find one of its required files, possibly
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - 
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - because it was unable to create it in the folder. Please make
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - 
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - sure that the folder in which this application was downloaded is
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - 
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - accessible and not read-only.
2016-06-17 13:05:53,487 [INFO ] - 
2016-06-17 13:05:53,503 [DEBUG] - Command ["C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\dotnet-461\4.6.01055.006\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /log "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\net461.log" ] exited with '3'.
2016-06-17 13:05:53,518 [ERROR] - ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\dotnet-461\4.6.01055.006\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /log "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\net461.log" ] was not successful. Exit code was '3'. See log for possible error messages.
2016-06-17 13:05:53,518 [DEBUG] - Built-in PowerShell host called with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'c:\choco\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'c:\choco\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'c:\choco\lib\dotnet-461\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1' -installArguments '' -packageParameters '''] exited with '3'.
2016-06-17 13:05:53,534 [DEBUG] - Calling command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a']
2016-06-17 13:05:53,549 [DEBUG] - Command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a'] exited with '1116'
```

So a couple of things:

- No log file is produced for the DotNet installer...so it doesn't look like it's successfully launching the installer.
- The installer package is definitely downloaded to the expected location. Not sure why it would be able to download the installer to this directory but then later not access/run it.
- If I RDP onto the box and run the "choco install dotnet4.6.1" command as a local admin the package installs with no errors.
- I'm now running choco 0.9.10 but had the same issue with 0.9.9
- I'm running the newer version of the dotnet4.6.1 installer (unapproved) that runs in /q (quite) mode instead of /passive.  I had the same issue in Passive mode.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: While having used choco a bit, I don't know enough to know why your issue is occuring. But, if you're interested in a different method, I have installed .net with a custom script extension, and with an azure automation dsc script. I can post an answer with either/both of these if you want?

Comment: Hi @EdRixon , if you have a way to install 4.6.1 using DSC directly, that would be awesome.  Note:  I have also tried cDotNetFramework using the GraniResource DSC modules.  While this did work for me with 4.6, I couldn't manage to make it work for 4.6.1...it kept bombing on me for some reason and I couldn't discern from the messages what the ultimate issue was.  If you have a DSC solution that works for 4.6.1 I would love to see it.

Comment: Not completely sure what the issue is, but here's how we find out. There is a complete log file with debug/verbose output. If you put that in a Gist somewhere and link to it, it will help with determining what may be wrong. You can also jump into https://gitter.im/chocolatey/chocolatey.org when you run into issues and want a little bit more interactive help (it's the little chat icon in the bottom right corner on https://chocolatey.org).

Comment: @ferventcoder : I'll try to gather some more information on this and send it your way...but I've also been having some issues with Choco finding files on a custom zip installation of event-store and also while installing NSSM. It seems like choco sometimes tries to access something before the files are ready/fully extracted/etc...  Not 100% sure...I'll follow up and send you more info when I look further into our NSSM and EventStore installs.

Comment: @swannee I'm just trying to confirm this as I haven't seen any news from msft, but does the 2012 r2 image now come with .net 461 already installed? It appears it does, but my paranoia of no announcement prevents me taking the script to install it out of my deploy...

Comment: @EdRixon Yes it appears that 4.6.1 is now included on the standard image...that should speed up my provisioning a fair amount.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not saying this is the best answer possible, but this works both via Chocolatey (launched directly from a CustomScript ARM extension) or via DSC (using a pull server and a custom DSC module for .Net 4.6.1) when either is initiated from an ARM template.  Below is from my chocolateyInstall.ps1. I'm basically manually conducting the install instead of relying on the chocolatey install functionality. This came from [the following SO question](https://superuser.com/a/1041608/389278) which used this approach for 4.5.2.

```
Function IsInstalled {
    $ver = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full').Release
    return (!($ver -eq $null) -and ($ver -ge 394254))
}

if (IsInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later is already installed"
}
else {
    $SourceURI = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/9/35980F81-60F4-4DE3-88FC-8F962B97253B/NDP461-KB3102438-Web.exe"
    $FileName = $SourceURI.Split('/')[-1]
    $BinPath = Join-Path $env:SystemRoot -ChildPath "Temp\$FileName"

    if (!(Test-Path $BinPath))
    {
        Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $SourceURI -OutFile $BinPath
    }

    write-verbose "Installing .Net 4.6.1 from $BinPath"
    write-verbose "Executing $Binpath /q /norestart"
    Sleep 5
    Start-Process -FilePath $BinPath -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -Wait -NoNewWindow            
    Sleep 5
    Write-Verbose "DotNet 4.6.1 Install completed"
}
```

Comment: I should note that the latest version of Chocolatey 0.9.10.3 resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the delay. So you need to have an automation account. I have modified my template deployment script to create the automation account, then with the Get-AzureRmAutomationRegistrationInfo cmdlet, i get the primary key and endpoint like so:

```
$RegistrationInfo = Get-AzureRmAutomationRegistrationInfo `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -AutomationAccountName $AccountName

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
    -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
    # extra params here
    -RegistrationKey ($RegistrationInfo.PrimaryKey | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) `
    -RegistrationUrl $RegistrationInfo.Endpoint `
    -AutomationAccountName $AccountName
```

Then in the template itself, you have an automation account there as well (name from param), and as child resources of that, a configuration and a compilation.

See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e69b8237-358a-4652-b588-fbc94f228018/script-compilation-warningsevery-time?forum=azureautomation) for automation account part of the template and the configuration. (I was doing the same thing v recently, with issues, but it works in the end.) As you can see, the configuration is a script that downloads .net installer and installs. FYI, this requires a reboot, so if you have anything else going on on the vm during deploy, you may get conflicts.

Like I said, you can also do it with a custom script extension if you want. Msft have a script on service profiler site that does it:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": false,
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [ "https://serviceprofiler.azurewebsites.net/content/downloads/InstallNetFx46.ps1" ],
            "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File InstallNetFx46.ps1"
        },
        "forceUpdateTag": "RerunExtension"
    },
    "name": "CustomScriptExtensionInstallNet46"
}
```

Comment: Ed, thanks for the answer, in my case I'm not using AzureAutomation, just my own hosted DSC server (on an azure vm).  I'll post what I did to get it working shortly.

Comment: Sure, just a different DSC source...I'm sure this would also work with a hosted DSC server.  My solution below appeared to work so I'm going that way so I can leverage Choco.