# Unattended install of .net framework 4.6.2 using DSC

Tags: .net, powershell, dsc

I'm trying to install 4.6.2 on a number of servers in an automated way (no implementation of WSUS or otherwise).  My goal was to leverage PowerShell DSC as we are configuring other aspects that way.

However, the resources I've tried (xHotfix from xWindowsUpdate and xPackage from xPSDesiredStateConfiguration) have failed.  xHotfix says the downloaded files are invalid (from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3151800) and the native Package and xPackage resources require a ProductId...which doesn't seem to be available either.

Has anyone successfully deployed 4.6.2 via PowerShell DSC that can provide some pointers?

Comment: chocolatey is an option is all else fails: https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnet4.6.2

Comment: I thought of Chocolatey as well; issue is that I cannot confirm (right now) that servers have internet access otherwise I would use it too

Comment: There is a workaround for that if you know what packages you are installing in advance. You can copy the installer from a local share to the chocolatey cache folder and choco will then use the installer from cache.

Comment: @JamesC. thanks, that's good to know as well though sounds a bit more involved in that, correct me if I'm wrong, I'd have to have another resource(s) that copies the desired packages to Chocolatey cache then invoke chocoloatey?  Or set up a chocolately proxy server or something similar...correct?

Comment: Is it me or does anyone else think this is ugly and/or stupid?  4.6.2 (and others before it) are advertised as Windows Updates. Yet they aren't packaged that way as evident by the fact you can't use WUSA.exe to install them...yet, if you run `get-hotfix` they'll show up in the list and are also present under "Installed Updates" in Add/Remove Programs...

Likely barking up a tree here since .Net Core is the future but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from another SO question ([Failure Installing DotNet 4.6.1 via Chocolatey using DSC cChocoPackageInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885696/failure-installing-dotnet-4-6-1-via-chocolatey-using-dsc-cchocopackageinstaller)) I opted to develop a custom resource to handle this because I'm not a fan of script resources as they feel brittle...

Both options (using a script or using a script resource) would work as well. I just chose to develop a custom resource for more control.

Comment: This is definitely the better way to go if your willing to put in the time/effort to create the custom resource.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer until I hear something better...would prefer to use windows update to apply the update but doesn't look like that's possible...

Comment: @HBoyce - just wondering if you ever found a more straightforward way to get this to work? I was amazed to find it's not straightforward to install .NET with DSC :(

Comment: @RobDavis not really... I haven't had a need to do much of this recently so haven't spent significant time developing the solution beyond the custom resource -- which solved the problem.  Still open to other suggestions.

Comment: @HBoyce - I came across this [GraniResource](https://github.com/guitarrapc/GraniResource) module which has a resource for doing offline .NET installs. So, same as your approach I gather. Is your resource publicly available by chance?

Comment: @RobDavis right now, no the module isn't available open source (doesn't mean it can't be just isn't). I did look at the module referenced and can tell you that it is far higher quality - at least by memory and brief analysis. As in, I don't believe I handle uninstall scenarios and certainly did not have extensive exit code analysis. I can investigate open sourcing the module but this far, grani seems to know best :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I've found the best fallback to be just using the script resource to do the install.  Create a check script that checks the version of .NET and then a script to go ahead and do the install if it's not at 4.6.2 already.  I use the same method to deploy .exe based application installers.